# Personalize file upload popup window

Tags: html

```
<input type="file" name="somename" />
```

I want to personalize the popup window by showing a message in the filename file. Which opens on the click of browse button of `<input>` type file.

Comment: "the popup window" *Which* popup window?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about customising the standard browser `<input type="file" ... />` file browsing window/interface, then this simply isn't possible.

You could however re-create your own interface/solution in Flash, but this is well outside the scope of this question, and probably not the best idea anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Trap the `click` event on the file `<input>` element. You can then display a message using `alert()` or an option to cancel with `confirm()`. Use `preventDefault()` to prevent the file upload dialog from showing.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/AX2s9/

Script:

```js
document.getElementById( 'file' ).addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {
    if( !confirm( 'A message before the file dialog. Are you sure you want to upload a file?' ) ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    };
} );
```

HTML:

```html
<input id="file" type="file" />
```